# Nested Form, "Can't mass-assign protected attributes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, mass-assignment

This is the relevant part of my nested form:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.fields_for "@partcode" do |p|%> 

  <%= p.label "partcode"%><br />
  <%= p.text_field :partcode %>

<% end %>
</div>
```

and i already have this in my model:

```
attr_accessible :partcode,
                :description
```

yet when i enter something in to the form, i get this error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: @partcode
```

Here is my partcode model:

```
class Partcode < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :partcode,
              :description

  validates       :partcode,
              :description,
              :presence => true

 belongs_to "goods_ins"

 accepts_nested_attributes_for "goods_ins"


end
```

and here is all the code from my goods in model:

```
class GoodsIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :c4lpono, 
              :courier, 
              :deliverydate,  
              :deliverynoteno,  
              :description,  
              :destination,  
              :notes,  
              :partcode,  
              :quantity,  
              :signedby,  
              :suppliername

  validates       :deliverydate,  
              :deliverynoteno,  

              :destination,

              :quantity,  
              :signedby,  
              :suppliername,
              :presence => true

 has_many :suppliers

 has_many :partcodes

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :partcodes
end
```

Also here is the `new` part of my partcode controller:

```
def new
@partcode = Partcode.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @partcode }
end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to loose the "" around `@partcode`?

Comment: yup, then it comes up with:
 undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: Then you haven't instantiated the `@partcode` inside your controller. Try writing inside your controller action: `@partcode = Partcode.new` (or whatever the class is).

Comment: that's already in my controller.. i forgot to explain in more depth, the form is for a table called goods_in, but this nested part is for a table called partcode..

Comment: Ok..The `GoodsIn` model has the following declaration inside it's class definition? `accepts_nested_attributes_for :partcode`. Also is this a one-to-one relationship or one-to-many?

Comment: `@partcode = GoodsIn.partcodes.build` on your controller.

Comment: yeh already has that in the class definition, its a one-to-many relationship. if i put `@partcode = GoodsIn.partcodes.build` in my goods in controller i get this error: `undefined method 'partcodes' for #<Class:0x7f3e3c19aec0>`

Answer (score 7):

Should'nt you have :partcode_attributes to attr_accessible(in GoodsIn Model), like this:

```
attr_accessible :partcode_attributes
```

Assuming your model association is configured that way. hope it helps

Comment: added that in there and i'm still getting `undefined method 'partcodes' for #<Class:0x7f3e3c29b4a0>`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to look at your model. But attr_accessible isn't an instance. I think it should just say this

```
<%= f.fields_for "partcode" do |p|%>`
```

than in your controller  :

```
@partcode = Partcode.new(params["partcode"])
```

Comment: tried that and i get this: `undefined local variable or method 'params' for GoodsInsController:Class`

Comment: Ah ok, throw in a debugger right after `def create` . What is being returned after you submit?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments from your answer i believe you can use the `build` method made for `has_one` relanshionships:

```
@partcode = GoodsIn.build_partcode
```

SO your form can be like this:

```
<%= f.fields_for @partcode do |p|%>
```

Comment: tried that and i got `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Answer (score 0):

Your model has to have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :partcode` or it won't accept it's attributes.

Also `Partcode` class has to have his attributes white listed too.

**UPDATE:**

The `@partcode` must have a new `Partcode` in it. Make sure you set `@partcode = @goods_in.partcodes.build` or a simple `@partcode = Partcode.new`.

The fields for on the form should be like this `<%= f.fields_for @partcode do |p| %>`, without the quotes too.

Comment: please see my updated answer with my code from both models :)

Comment: @CarlaDessi what is being inserted in the `@partcode` variable?

Comment: um.. what ever is typed into the text field in the form? sorry if that's not what you mean..

Comment: @CarlaDessi the classes seem to be setup correctly, so the error seems to be from what is in the `@partcode` instance variable. Please post the controller code that sets `@partcode`, it is probably not being initialized with `GoodsIn.partcodes.build`

Comment: my partcode controller has quite a lot in it, but i'm guessing you need this bit:   
`@partcode = GoodsIn.build_partcode

  def partcode

    @partcode = Partcode.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @partcode }`

Comment: also i already have this in my controller `@partcode = Partcode.new`

Comment: @CarlaDessi please update your answer with the `new` action of your controller, and possibly with the stack trace of the error your receive. Without all the parts of the problem, we're just guessing here.